# Why is removing a spare tire from the trunk so time consuming

Tags: spare-tire

With every car I've owned this nut holding the spare tire in place needs a million turns to disengage (or re-engage). Why?

[image: spare tire with nut]

Comment: This sounds more like a rant than a real question.

Comment: You can shorten the hold down bolt, I did this for my honda

Comment: Leave the nut off for NASCAR speed tire changeover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the bolt & thread is still long enough when tires of different sizes are used.

Edit based on comment:
Many cars can have different wheel diameter and widths as standard, usually specified when ordering the car and often changed during the life of the car by those owners who wish to.

My own car can come from the factory with 16", 17" or even 18" as standard and iirc 19" can also be fitted.

And as for the spare that is usually one of those space savers limited to 50kmh...

Comment: Marked this answer as correct. I'm still not satisfied, but that's not @Solar Mike's fault. As a practical matter, there is exactly one tire that will ever be stored in that space.

Comment: @jsf80238 It's entirely possible that the manufacturer thought the additional cost to order up new shorter bolts for this use wasn't worth the cost, and just continued to use the bolts already in the system. In the cosmic scheme of things, I don't think it matters.